# Cross domain requests not working in SignalR 2.0.0-rc1

Tags: c#, signalr, cors

I recently upgraded a project from SignalR 2.0.0-beta1 to 2.0.0-rc1. I understand that in RC1, configuration of support for cross domain requests changed. I've updated my project to use the new syntax however I'm now getting the following error when attempting to communicate with my hub:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   =1377623738064">http://localhost:8080/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&=1377623738064.
>   Origin `http://localhost:7176` is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The client site is running at `http://localhost:7176` and the hub is listening via a console application at `http://localhost:8080`. Am I missing something here? Cross domain requests were working before I upgraded to RC1.

**CONSOLE APP ENTRY POINT**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var chatServer = new ChatServer();
    string endpoint = "http://localhost:8080";

    chatServer.Start(endpoint);

    Console.WriteLine("Chat server listening at {0}...", endpoint);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**CHATSERVER CLASS**

```
public class ChatServer
{
    public IDisposable Start(string url)
    {
        return WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);
    }
}
```

**STARTUP CONFIGURATION**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            map.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = true });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something is wrong with your client configuration.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load =1377623738064">http://localhost:8080/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&=1377623738064. Origin http://localhost:7176 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

The negotiate request should be made to `http://localhost:8080/signalr/negotiate?...` not `http://localhost:8080/negotiate?...`. To fix this you can try the following before you call $.connection.hub.start:

`$.connection.hub.url = http://localhost:8080/signalr;`

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. I got so focused on the fact that I had changed the approach to cross domain configuration I didn't realize I had inadvertently changed something else as well. Thanks.

Comment: So what's the best way to handle the cross domain in signalR when there are multiple environments involved for the server side e.g. dev, uat and production? I mean is there any way apart from manually changing the hub connection in the each generated hub file?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this question has been adequately answered, but I made the following changes to the sample provided by Microsoft:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HubConfiguration();
            config.EnableJSONP = true;
            app.MapSignalR(config);
        }
```

And I added the following to the JS sample:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () {
    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
        // Call the Send method on the hub.
        chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
        // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
        $('#message').val('').focus();
    });
});
```

And now the Cross domain scripting is enabled. Hope this helps someone else, I was really puzzling with it for a while.

Comment: Looked all over for answers, and luckily found yours.  Thanks!

Comment: { jsonp: true } Upvote for this.
Does it foce to use json? or it just allows it to be used?

Comment: @Tauseef - Adding the JSONP flag does enforce the use of JSON as the message transport, as JSONP is a way of passing JSON data across different domains, please see: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about[/link]

Answer (score 5):

For Microsoft.Owin 2.x and above:

Add `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package via NuGet by this command in Package Manager console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

and then `using` this package in `Startup` class file:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
```

then change your source code like this:

```
// app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.MapSignalR();
```

Comment: In SiganlR 2.2: app.UseCors() is not there any more.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to handle Cross Domain is documented here
[CrossDomain Signal R](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain)